# CrossTab with multiple column headings in Access VBA

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, crosstab

I have a table with this structure  ("Spot" is the place were the item is stored and "N" is the number of items in that spot).

```
Id | Spot1 | N1 | Spot2 | N2 | Spot3 | N3 |
1  |   A   | 2  |   B   | 2  |   C   | 1  |
2  |   B   | 2  |   C   | 1  |   D   | 2  |
3  |   A   | 2  |   C   | 1  |   D   | 5  |
```

I want to run a query on that table and create a table like this:

```
ID | A | B | C | D |
1  | 2 | 2 | 1 | _ |
2  | _ | 2 | 1 | 2 |
3  | 2 | _ | 1 | 5 |
```

I would like some help on deciding the best strategy to build this query.

I was thinking of creating  several crosstab queries with different column heading and somehow merge those crosstab tables together.

Is that a good way to go or is there something more efficient. My example has only 4 different items but my actual table has around 20 items so the final table would have 20 columns and over 200 records.

Comment: You could, as you say, make 20 crosstabs but then you have to splice all those back together via an ugly FROM clause or using a messy set of lookups or stepping through each query by hand in VBA. Doesn't it seem better to reverse those steps and make a table or query of 3 Columns (ID, Spot, N) ?? Multiple ways to get there. Then you can crosstab that.

Comment: That's an idea, but then I would have multiple row for one ID in that table.

Comment: Not after you crosstab it. The ID column in the intermediate query does NOT have to be unique. Rename it from ID to OrigID or something if you prefer. The ID field in the query is merely an ordinary integer field. What is unique in the intermediate query is the combination of ID and Spot. But neither has to be unique independently (and shouldn't be). Tables have autonumbers not queries. I pulled that ID into the query so that you could use it in the `GROUP BY` of the crosstab.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend splicing first and then crosstabbing. We can do this using an intermediate three column table of your source ID, Spot and Amount. The following code is one general method that makes no assumptions about how many columns are in your source table.  Nor does it make assumptions about how many spots exist. It does assume the table tmpTbl already exists.

```
Sub largeCrossTab()
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset, rst2 As DAO.Recordset
    Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Table1")
    Dim fld As DAO.Field
    CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE FROM tmpTbl"
    For Each fld In rst.Fields
        If InStr(fld.Name, "Spot") > 0 Then
            CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO tmpTbl(OrigID, Spot, Amount) " _
                & "SELECT ID, " & fld.Name & ", N" & Right(fld.Name, Len(fld.Name) - 4) _
                & " FROM Table1"
        End If
    Next
    Set rst2 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("TRANSFORM Nz(Sum(Amount), '_') " _
        & "SELECT OrigID " _
        & "FROM tmpTbl " _
        & "GROUP BY OrigID " _
        & "PIVOT Spot")

    ''' Do something with rst2 '''

    Set rst = Nothing
    Set rst2 = Nothing
    Set fld = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Will see how slow it gets when I will have thousands of entries in table1 (Right now a 400 row table1 generates a 2000 raw tmptbl). But for now it works, Thanks !

Comment: @user3638420 If the data gets so big that you are concerned about performance, you will probably want to crosstab less data at a time. In such a case, you can rehash the logic so that you determine what columns will exist and thereby create the output table structure at the beginning. Then you can perform INSERT statements against the output table with a TRANSFORM of just Spot1/N1 then a TRANSFORM of just Spot2/N2 and so on.